# Query in hbase filter

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop-streaming

i have to filter string in one column starts with "hi" and ends with "bye"

I am able to get this:

```
scan 'table',
 {COLUMNS => ['data:title'],
  FILTER => "SingleColumnValueFilter('data', 'title', = , 'substring:hi') 
  "}
```

but not sure how to compare `endswith`

Answer (score 0):

We can use the below filter to get it:

```
scan 'table',
     {COLUMNS => ['data:title'],
      FILTER => "SingleColumnValueFilter('data', 'title', = , 'regexstring:*bye') 
      "}
```